Align first row of text in table to baseline of surrounding text
Is there a way to align the text inside a table to surrounding text? I cant find a question like this anywhere. Seems like it should be do-able without having to resort to replacing the table with divs.


baseline surrounding text here <table style="display: inline-block; background-color: rgba(20,30,40,0.5);"><tr><td>align me to baseline</td></tr><tr><td>abc</td></tr><tr><td>def</td></tr></table>



What I'm trying to achieve:


can you add an image/screenshot of what is the output that you expect here?

see my edit above



baseline surrounding text here

<table style="display: inline-table; vertical-align: baseline; background-color: rgba(20,30,40,0.5);">
    <tr><td>align me to baseline</td></tr>
    <tr><td>abc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>def</td></tr>
</table>






baseline surrounding text here <table style="border-spacing: 0px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; background-color: rgba(20,30,40,0.5);"><tr><td>align me to baseline</td></tr><tr><td>abc</td></tr><tr><td>def</td></tr></table>



